# Wordpress Last post go to bottom

Tags: php, wordpress

Usually if we create a post post it come at the top of the list in blog page(categorey.php/archive.php). 
Is it possible to make the  latest post to go at the bottom of the list in those pages without using any plugin ?

Comment: If you want programmers to help you, you need to present a programming problem.... what have you tried, why it didn't work, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can back date your post, set a publish date to the last year or so.

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you shouldn't have to use a plugin to handle this, you can create a pretty basic page template that fetches posts in the order you'd like them. Since you know the templates you are working with, this is pretty simple.

Assuming you are wanting to simply reverse the order of the posts fetched by WordPress, you can query them in a reverse order within the templates. Natively, WordPress outputs posts in a chronological order, if you want to reverse them, you can use a combination of the following. The first line will fetch posts in a descending order, then will check if there are posts, and output them to the respective template, should there be any.

`query_posts('order=DESC');
if ( have_posts() ) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();`

Comment: $homepage = new WP_Query(
 array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => '12', //MAXIMUM DISPLAY OM HOMEPAGE
  'orderby'          => 'date',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
   array(
    'key'     => 'parent_slug',
    'value'   => "root",
    'compare' => '='
   )
  )
 )
);
$collection = $homepage->get_posts();   What can I do for this ? thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume this would be the query that is ran on the homepage, for the order of the posts to be reveres, as previously mentioned you would need to change the 'order' value from 'ASC' to 'DESC', like so:  
`$homepage = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'post', 
'post_status' => 'publish', 
'posts_per_page' => '12',  
'orderby' => 'date', 
'order' => 'DESC', 
'meta_query' => array( array( 
 'key' => 'parent_slug', 'value' => "root", 'compare' => '=' ))) 
); 
$collection = $homepage->get_posts();`